# Hover over parent and show child

Tags: css

I have a dynamic mega menu that shows the first tier of submenus but I'm trying to make it so that the second tier show up when an element in the 1st tier is hovered over. currently both tiers and showing up taking up a lot of space.

I found a post on here saying to use this layout:

```
.child{ display:none; }
.parent:hover .child{ display:block; }
```

It's kind of tricky with the css I have:

```
child = .new-menu .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.burt
parent =  .dropdown-menu.burt .new-menu .dropdown-submenu > a
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
.new-menu .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.burt{
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-menu.burt .new-menu .dropdown-submenu > a:hover .new-menu .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.burt  {
    display: block; 
}
```

Targeting these specific elements seems tricky and the only way I could get them specifically was the mess I have above. Maybe I can target these elements a better way, or another way of making this work?

### Update

Here is the html structure, it's kind trick, it's from Americommerce and it uses 'Merge Codes' that supply the dynamic data

This is the main structure:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <ac:layoutarea id="Item">
            <ac:visibilityarea id="phDDLink">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" target="$$TARGET$$">$$TEXT$$</a>
                <ac:visibilityarea id="phSubMenu">

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu mm2">
                    <div class="row"> $$SUBMENU$$</div>
                  </ul>

                </ac:visibilityarea>
              </li>
            </ac:visibilityarea>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="phNoDDLink">
              <li>
                <a href="$$HREF$$" target="$$TARGET$$">$$TEXT$$</a>
              </li>
            </ac:visibilityarea>
          </ac:layoutarea>

        </ul>
```

This is the structure of the sub-menus:

```
<ac:layoutarea id="SubItem">

      <ac:visibilityarea id="phDDLink">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"> 
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="$$HREF$$" target="$$TARGET$$">$$TEXT$$</a>
            <ac:visibilityarea id="phSubMenu">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu burt" id="">$$SUBMENU$$</ul>

            </ac:visibilityarea>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ac:visibilityarea>
      <ac:visibilityarea id="phNoDDLink">

        <li class="greg">
          <a href="$$HREF$$" target="$$TARGET$$">$$TEXT$$</a>
        </li>

      </ac:visibilityarea>

    </ac:layoutarea>
```

### Update 2

HTML from inspector

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu mm2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a  class="sub-link" href="/store/c/software.aspx" target="">Software</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu burt">
                <div class="new-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="/office-2019.aspx" target="">Products</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu burt">
                            <li class="greg"> <a href="/product1.aspx" target="">Product 1</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

### Update 3

I added a class to the first `<a>` and then added this css:

```
.new-menu .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.burt {
    display: none;
}
.sub-link:hover .new-menu .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.burt {
    display: block;

}
```

It hides the elements but showing them on hover still doesn't work

```css
.sub-link{
  display: block;
}

.new-menu{
  display: none;
}

.greg
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a  class="sub-link" href="/store/c/software.aspx" target="">Software</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu burt">
                <div class="new-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> 
                    <a href="/office-2019.aspx" target="">
                      Products
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu burt">
                            <li class="greg">
                            <a href="/product1.aspx" target="">Product 1
                            </a> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: can you provide a html sample for this? would like to see your html structure so we could come up a solution.

Comment: I think you should first find the main parent and which can impact the whole dom

Comment: Can you please provice the HTML code snippet  ? :(

Comment: You can do one more thing, copy the HTML structure or code from browser, just pressF12 and  > inspect Element > Copy Menu structure if you can :)

Comment: Can you control the CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is not clear so I tried to create my own and try to recreate your problem

have a look

```css
.new-menu{
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu{
   display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
}

.mainParent:hover .new-menu{
  display: block;
}


.mainParent:hover .dropdown-submenu{
  display: block;
}

.mainParent:hover .dropdown-menu{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="mainParent"> 
  Link
  <div class="new-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-submenu">
      <div class="dropdown-menu burt">
        Application Menu
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

If each element having a property to hide, then each element class have to make visible on parent element hover.

---

If you are facing some kind of nested DOM CSS problem, you can see this running code snippet

```css
.sub-link{
  display: block;
}

.new-menu{
  display: none;
}

.greg
{
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover a{
  color: red !important;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .burt{
  display: block;
  color: red !important;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover .new-menu{
  display: block;
  color: red !important;
}

.new-menu:hover .burt{
  display: block;
}

.new-menu:hover .greg{
  display: block;
}
.new-menu:hover a{
  display: block;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a  class="sub-link" href="/store/c/software.aspx" target="">Software</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu burt">
                <div class="new-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> 
                    <a href="/office-2019.aspx" target="">
                      Products
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu burt">
                            <li class="greg">
                            <a href="/product1.aspx" target="">Product 1
                            </a> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: I tried implementing some of this, and Ive gotten closer, but I still cant get hover to work. The items are hidden though. I made updates to my post to show what I changed. If you have any more suggestions I welcome them!

Comment: I Modified your Question and added one more code snippet, is this kind of problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add another class for your child elements and to your parent element.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .f-red {color:red;}
    .childEl{
    display:none;
    }
    #parentEl {padding: 5px; border-style: solid;}
    #parentEl:hover > .childEl {display:block}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="parentEl">
    <h1 class="childEl f-red">Child</h1>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```